# Why does Angular binding fail when using <input type="file"/>?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm far from an expert on Angular, so I have to try asking a question here. I've added the possibility to upload files in may AngularJS project. I need to display the selected filename in a textbox (or preferably a read-only field) before the user submits the form. It contains a number of fields that need validation. The problem is, the selected filename never shows up. The textblock is still empty after selecting a file. I've tried the following code (Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Ll3GZdpp8Tsqwvo0W1ax):

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Custom Plunker</title>
  <script data-require="jquery@2.1.3" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="3.3.2" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/css/ng-grid.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://angular-ui.github.com/ng-grid/lib/ng-grid.debug.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
              Välj fil... <input type="file" onchange=" angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this) ">
                                        </span>
      <input type="text" ng-model="organizationSettings.logotypeFileName" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.organizationSettings = {};

  $scope.setFile = function(element) {
    $scope.fileToUpload = element.files[0];
    console.log($scope.fileToUpload.name);
    $scope.organizationSettings.logotypeFileName = $scope.fileToUpload.name;
  };    
});
```

css:

```
.btn-file {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-file input[type=file] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    font-size: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    outline: none;
    background: white;
    cursor: inherit;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: you can not use modern version of angular?

Comment: What version is modern? 2.0?

Comment: I didnt mean most modern. 1.2 or 1.3 is ok, answers given by others works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ng-change for file upload because binding is not supported for file upload in angularjs., its an issue in angularjs.

In other cases while you are using `ng-change`(other than file upload) you have to use `ng-model` to make the ng-change directive work in order to trigger change based on it(so only you are getting `"Error: No controller: ngModel"`) while using it.

The best possible solution is you manually trigger `$scope.$apply()` to make binding to the input model while programatically setting it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you are using `onchange` which is an event outside of any of angular's directives.

Whenever you use an event outside of angular that changes the scope, you need to notify that a digest is needed to update the part of the view managed by that scope by using `$apply`

The simplest fix is to use `ng-change` instead of native `onchange`. All of angulars event handling directives will trigger `$apply` internally

The alternative (not best approach) would be keep the onchange and do:

```
$scope.setFile = function(element) {  
    $scope.fileToUpload = element.files[0];
    console.log($scope.fileToUpload.name);
    $scope.organizationSettings.logotypeFileName = $scope.fileToUpload.name;

    $scope.$apply();
};
```

Comment: I can't get ng-change to trigger. If I just change inching into ng-change, I also get "Error: No controller: ngModel". The second solution works, why is it a bad idea?

Comment: no idea how that error comes up unless your code is outside of ng-app? As for second part...far better to keep code under on framework and let angular itself do all the data watching and is easier to test

Answer (score 1):

I think that binding changes could be done easier, and I will explain below how to do it.  By setting  a ng-model  to the input, it will automatically bind the input control to the variable defined in your controller's scope. Therefore, if you specify a new file, it will automatically update the model $scope.fileToUpload. This goes the other way around: any change in $scope.fileToUpload done in JS, will be reflected in the DOM.

**index.html** -  try to replace

```
<input type="file" onchange=" angular.element(this).scope().setFile(this) ">
```

with

```
<input type="file" ng-model="fileToUpload">
```

In app.js, you could get rid of:

```
$scope.setFile = function(element) {
    $scope.fileToUpload = element.files[0];
    console.log($scope.fileToUpload.name);
    $scope.organizationSettings.logotypeFileName = $scope.fileToUpload.name;
  };
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I need to get the files array from the input-tag.